# Apply condition that multiple values occur in related data

Tags: sql

I have this table `TCM`:

[image]

I want to select different `Topic_hd_id` from `TCM` where `TCM.VALUE` is from another temp table `T`.

For example, temp table `T` has value `1000,4`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TOPIC_HD_ID) 
FROM TRN.TOPICS_CATEGORY_MAPPING AS TCM 
WHERE TCM.VALUE IN(1000,4)
```

It shows:

[image]

But  I need to apply `WHERE VALUE=1000 AND VALUE=4`.

Result must be only one row with `TPIC_HD_ID = 255` but while using `IN` it shows 3 rows.

Comment: Please do not put your title in CAPITALS and make it more meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  TOPIC_HD_ID 
FROM 
  TRN.TOPICS_CATEGORY_MAPPING AS TCM 
WHERE 
  TCM.VALUE IN(1000, 4) 
group by 
  TOPIC_HD_ID 
having 
  count(distinct TCM.VALUE)= 2
```

Comment: thanks ,but  here 1000,4 from another table T so the quey become SELECT TOPIC_HD_ID
FROM TRN.TOPICS_CATEGORY_MAPPING AS TCM 
WHERE TCM.VALUE IN(SELECT VALUE FROM T)
GROUP BY TOPIC_HD_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT VALUE) = 2    what is 2 ..? how to change if the value from other table

Comment: Just use join between two tables

Answer (score 1):

Extra `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT TOPIC_HD_ID
FROM TRN.TOPICS_CATEGORY_MAPPING AS TCM 
WHERE TCM.VALUE IN(1000,4)
GROUP BY TOPIC_HD_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT VALUE) = 2
```

And as the alternative - using `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT TOPIC_HD_ID
FROM TRN.TOPICS_CATEGORY_MAPPING AS TCM 
WHERE TCM.VALUE IN(1000)
INTERSECT
SELECT TOPIC_HD_ID 
FROM TRN.TOPICS_CATEGORY_MAPPING AS TCM 
WHERE TCM.VALUE IN(4)
```

Comment: Thanks , here 1000,4 from another table T so the quey become SELECT TOPIC_HD_ID
FROM TRN.TOPICS_CATEGORY_MAPPING AS TCM 
WHERE TCM.VALUE IN(SELECT VALUE FROM T)
GROUP BY TOPIC_HD_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT VALUE) = 2    what is 2 ..? i did understand that

Comment: Yes, right. Also, in this case an example with `INTERSECT` will not work